# How to use useParams() with nested route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

How to use URL parameters with nest routed ?

Hello, I want to build an e-commerce page which shows a single product.

So, I use `useParams()` to extract props from URL and use `filter()` to render single item.

But the 3rd party API return me an ID with slash symbol.

e.g.

```
{
  [
    id: 'electronics/2020/product1'
  ],
  [
    id: 'sportwear/product2'
  ]
}
```

When I get data from `useParams()`, it will return only `electronics` or `sportwear`. Not the entire ID

How to get the entire ID from using React Router DOM

P.S. Do I miss something ? Do I have to use `useRouthMatch()` ?

---

My files

```
// Route
<Route path="/view/:id" component={SingleProduct} />

// Link from map()

state.map(product => <Link to={product.id}>{product.title}</Link>);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you've not any nested routing, and a couple of options.

### Option 1

Convert the `id` fields to strings that don't resolve to route path segments. Use [String.prototype.replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) to replace all the `"/"` with some other sentinel character, like `"_"`.

```
state.map(product => (
  <Link to={product.id.replaceAll("/", "_")}>
    {product.title}
  </Link>
));
```

You can then later split the string on the sentinel character.

Examples:

```
const { id } = useParams();
```

- ```
  const [section, year, product] = id.split("_"); // 'electronics/2020/product1'
  ```
- ```
  const [section, product] = id.split("_");       // 'sportwear/product2'
  ```

### Option 2

Explicitly declare routes for all the categories. Remember to order the routes from more specific to least specific when within a `Switch` component.

Example:

```
<Route
  exact
  path={[
    "/view/:section/:year/:productId", // '/view/electronics/2020/product1'
    "/view/:section/:productId"        // '/view/sportwear/product2'
  ]}
  component={SingleProduct}
/>
```

Access the route's match params in the `SingleProduct` component.

```
const { section, year, productId } = useParams();
```